Can't convert UTF-8 characters from HTTP_REFERER in PHP
I'm capturing the complete address from the url by using HTTP_REFERER in PHP, but I have a GET parameter called Name that may have some utf-8 characters such as spanish accents in some cases or the letter "ñ". The thing is that "HTTP_REFERER" doesn't capture those characters really well.
The url I really want to capture: https://mywebsite.com/?name=María
The url I get with HTTP_Referer: https://mywebsite.com/?name=Mar%C3%ADa
Any ideas, please?
I tried using this code:
$url = utf8_decode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
$url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
$url = mb_internal_encoding($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"UTF-8");`

It doesn't work unfortunately.

For a URL that your having trouble with, post the original URL along with the version that appears in HTTP_Referer, the result from your code and the result you're trying to achieve. See[ask]

@TangentiallyPerpendicular thank you. I just did what you suggested and edited the question.

I think urldecode would be sufficient

@ChrisHaas That really worked just great! Thatnk you so much  :)

utf8_decode() converts to ISO-8859-1. Is that what you really want? You don't need ISO-8859-1 in 2024 unless it's a legacy system. If you mean to decode the parameter, that's something you always need, because even US-ASCII characters can have a special meaning in URL and need encoding.

Recommend use rawurldecode().

C3 AD is the UTF-8 encoded bytes for the í character.  In this case, you need to decode the URL into a byte string, where each %HH sequence represents a single byte, and then you can decode those bytes as UTF-8.

Try this:
$url=urldecode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

